# Generating series of numbers(Coordinates) based on single values

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, loops

Initial coordinate is :
`(a,b)=(2,3)`

```
(c,d) generate by (a+2,b+2)　i.e. (4,5)
(e,f)　must be generate by (a+2,b)　i.e (4,3)
```

For the next iteration `a and b` will be `c and d` of previous step:
i.e `(a,b) =(4,5)`
and goes like this.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; **asking us to write the program for you**, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator (pretty much a translate from your description):

```
def pattern(a, b):
    yield (a, b)
    while True:
        c, d = (a+2, b+2)
        e, f = (a+2, b)
        yield (c, d)
        yield (e, f)
        a, b = (c, d)
```

For example:

```
>>> def pattern(a, b):
...     yield (a, b)
...     while True:
...         c, d = (a+2, b+2)
...         e, f = (a+2, b)
...         yield (c, d)
...         yield (e, f)
...         a, b = (c, d)
... 
>>> g =  pattern(2, 3)
>>> [next(g) for _ in range(10)]
[(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 3), (6, 7), (6, 5), (8, 9), (8, 7), (10, 11), (10, 9), (12, 13)]
```